# sparql query to get a triplet related to other triples

Tags: rdf, sparql, triples

Supposing we have many RDF triples related as:

```
1: <S,P1,O>        

2: <O,P2,O3>       
3: <O,P3,O4>  

4: <O3,P4,O5>
```

I would like to get triple N° 2, 3 and 4 by just knowing triple number 1
because triple N° 2 and 3 share "O" with triple N°1
and triple N° 4 share "O3" with triple N°2 which share "O" with triple N°1
Is it possible to formulate that with sparql query without knowung P2,P3,P4?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you make any progress with this?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. This query will do that just that:

```
  CONSTRUCT {
     ?s ?p ?o . 
     ?o ?q ?z. 
     ?w ?r ?o .
  }
  WHERE {
        ?s ?p ?o . 
        FILTER (?s = :O || ?o = :O) 
        OPTIONAL { ?o ?q ?z . }
        OPTIONAL { ?w ?r ?o . }
   }
```

It's unlikely to be very efficient though. However without knowing more about your actual data or why you want this particular result, it's difficult to come up with a better solution.

Comment: Thank you but this query will create a triples, not just selecting!! I just need to select these triples in result not to create them

Comment: @BigNoob It's not clear what you mean by "select triples" then.  A SPARQL select query lets you get a set of results, each of which is a binding of a number of variables to resources.  You can bind a subject, object, and predicate to variables, if you want, but you're still just binding variables, not "selecting triples".

Comment: @BigNoob in your question you asked to "get triples". That is exactly what this query does.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra but i think Construct is different of select. Construct is for adding triples to triplestore and select is just to display results no?

Comment: No. CONSTRUCT is for retrieving triples from a triplestore. Not for adding them. SELECT also retrieves data from the store of course, but not in the form of triples (it retrieves sets of variable bindings instead).

Comment: @JeenBroekstra ahh ok Thank you for clarifying me. Well, i think the query that you have write is almost what i want but, in fact this query is special for the triples that o wrote (1,2,3,4) but what i need is a generic query for this kind of triples (related triples) I mean supposing that we have many other triples related to triple N°1 and N°3 what i have to do to get all triples related to the first one directly or indirectly related.

Comment: Then perhaps you should edit your question to indicate more clearly what it is you're after.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you know `:O` and you're asking for triples that have it as the subject, and triples that have the object of those triples as subjects.  Are you asking for something like this, then?

```
select * where {
  :O ?p2 ?o2 .
  optional { ?o2 ?p3 ?o3 }
}
```

Comment: yes i know :O and i want display in result: triples N° 2, 3 and 4 related to the first Triple directly and indirectly

Comment: @BigNoob Did that query help, then?